# How to connect MacPro 2013 Thunderbolt 2 to USB C

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, mac-pro

I see several posts about USB-C and TB-3 to TB-2 but are they reversible? As I cannot find a TB-2 to USB-3 device I thought maybe I could connect my MacPro (Late 2013) to a USB-C hub which has USB-3 ports. My primary purpose is to access storage devices not displays.

How can one go from TB-2 to USB-C or USB-3?

Answer (score 1):

You need a thunderbolt dock to convert the embedded USB signal when carried over thunderbolt 2.

They are not reversible either in a meaningful way.

Once TB2 is present you can use the TB3 to TB2 adapter bidirectionally.

Why not use the USB A ports to connect USB C?